# Netty NIO: Read received messages

Tags: java, sockets, web, netty

I am developing a client and server communication system using Netty NIO in Java. My code can be found [in the following repository](https://github.com/kristosh/netty-nio-Client-Server). Currently I am having one server and two clients and I am sending information from server to the clients and the opposite.

What I am trying to figure out, when I am receiving a message form the first client to the server, how can i send that message to the second client (and the opposite from client 2 to client 1). How can I send a message to a specific client?

I have noticed that my issues arised because of the way that I am trying to send the messages from the server. My code in serverHandler is the following:

```
for (Channel ch : channels1) {
    responseData.setIntValue(channels1.size());
    remoteAddr.add(ch.remoteAddress().toString());
    future = ch.writeAndFlush(responseData);
    //future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    System.out.println("the requested data from the clients are: "+requestData);
    responseData1.setStringValue(requestData.toString());
    future = ch.writeAndFlush(responseData1);
    System.out.println(future);
}
```

By default am sending a message about the number of the connections, but also when I am receiving message from the client 1 or 2 I want to send it back to 2 and 1. So I want to perform the communication between the two components. How can I send from the server to a specific client? I am not sure how can I send the messages back to the clients.

Comment: Could you please update the source code (GitHub) to be able to build it with Maven?

Comment: Am not familiar with maven, dont know how to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## General approach

Let's describe an approach to the problem.

When receiving data on the server side, use the remote address of the channel (the [`java.net.SocketAddress Channel.remoteAddress()` method](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#remoteAddress--)) to identify the client.

Such identification may be done using a map like: `Map<SocketAddress, Client>`, where the `Client` class or interface should contain the appropriate client connection (channel) associated context, including its `Channel`. Be sure to keep the map up-to-date: handle the «client connected» and «client disconnected» events appropriately.

After a client is identified, you may just send the appropriate messages to the clients, except the current sending client, using the client connection (channel) map.

Additionally, I would like to recommend you to find a good implementation of a chat application using Netty and to take a look at it.

## Netty-specific solution

Let's consider the server side implementation, in particular, the implementation of the `ProcessingHandler` class.

It already manages the active channels by representing them as the channel group:

```
static final ChannelGroup channels1 =
    new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
```

### Keeping the channel group up-to-date

The current implementation handles the «channel becomes active» event to keep the channel group up-to-date:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    channels1.add(ctx.channel());
    // ...
}
```

But this is only a half: it is necessary to handle the «channel becomes inactive» event symmetrically as well. The implementation should look like:

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    channels1.remove(ctx.channel());
}
```

### Broadcasting: Sending the received message to all channels, except the current one

To implement the desired behaviour, just update the implementation by introducing the appropriate check as follows:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    // ...

    for (Channel ch : channels1) {
        // Does `ch` represent the channel of the current sending client?
        if (ch.equals(ctx.channel())) {
            // Skip.
            continue;
        }

        // Send the message to the `ch` channel.
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

## Sending and receiving string problem

[Currently](https://github.com/kristosh/netty-nio-Client-Server/tree/33af05f8def5efdb21ac7989178c9f5d0cba3db2), the functionality around the `ResponseData` class is not present (not implemented).

The following **draft** changes are required to make both the client and the server work.

1. The `ResponseData` class: the `getStringValue` and `toString` methods should be corrected:

   ```
   String getStringValue() {
       return this.strValue;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return intValue + ";" + strValue;
   }
   ```
2. The `ResponseDataEncoder` class: it should use the string value:

   ```
   private final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

   @Override
   protected void encode(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final ResponseData msg, final ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
       out.writeInt(msg.getIntValue());
       out.writeInt(msg.getStringValue().length());
       out.writeCharSequence(msg.getStringValue(), charset);
   }
   ```
3. The `ResponseDataDecoder` class: it should use the string value:

   ```
   private final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

   @Override
   protected void decode(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final ByteBuf in, final List<Object> out) throws Exception {
       ResponseData data = new ResponseData();
       data.setIntValue(in.readInt());
       int strLen = in.readInt();
       data.setStringValue(in.readCharSequence(strLen, charset).toString());
       out.add(data);
   }
   ```
4. The `ClientHandler` class: it should correctly receive and handle the message:

   ```
   @Override
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
       final ResponseData responseData = (ResponseData) msg;
       System.out.println("The message sent from the server " + responseData);
       update.accept(responseData.getIntValue());
   }
   ```

## Additional references

1. [«SecureChat ‐ an TLS-based chat server, derived from the Telnet example», Netty Documentation](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html). In particular, the implementation of the [`SecureChatServerHandler` class](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatServerHandler.html).
2. [«Netty in Action», Norman Maurer, Marvin Allen Wolfthal (ISBN-13: 978-1617291470)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291471), «Part 3 — Network protocols», the «12.2 Our example WebSocket application» subchapter. Covers implementation of «a browser-based chat application».

Comment: What about the receiving of a message? I am not sure if i can read properly from the server. I can do so only when the server sends initially a message.

Comment: @konstantin, sorry, I have not got the full picture of the question. Could you please append the full description (with the source code) of the question to the initial question?

Comment: Actually what i want to do is when a client A sends a message to the serverm then the server needs to send it directly to the client B (and the opposite).

Comment: @konstantin, please see the update. Hope it will help you. I would like to recommend you to explore the «SecureChat» example.

Comment: What about the way am sending the message from the server to the client. It seems that I amm always receiving as a message 0. Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: @konstantin, could you please elaborate on the question (update your initial question with the details)? Currently, not observing anything like you have just described: using three clients started sequentially.

Comment: What is the normal behavior that i expect is that I want to send a message with the number of the connected clients in the server (which actually initialize the interface and a collaborative game will start only when i have two clients connected with the server). Also I want those clients to communicate each other using the server. Server receives info from then and then it needs to reply back the necessary information.

Comment: I used your example code. It seems that the server sends normally the information for the size of the connected channels always, however the info for the responseData1.setStringValue(requestData.toString()); is always zero.

Comment: I think that my code is handling as response only integer and am not sure how can i handle strings in the same way.

Comment: @konstantin, firstly, it looks like **that's another question**. Secondly, have just checked your repository. The source code there does not contain the line: `responseData1.setStringValue(requestData.toString());`. If you would like to continue the discussion, then push the latest version of the source code.

Comment: In that case my server handler cannot handle that case. I am receiving from the server strings but I cannot process them from the server and send them back to the client since the encoder and decoder classes are designed for integers. Am not sure how I can do the same for the case of strings.

Comment: @konstantin, I propose you should post that question as a separate one: the answer to the original question has been provided.

Comment: Actually this was my issue from the beginning. I could send the info but was zero always since it tried to read the integer and not the string.

Comment: The source code [there does not contain the line: responseData1.setStringValue(requestData.toString());](https://github.com/kristosh/netty-nio-Client-Server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=responseData1.setStringValue&type=). If you would like to continue the discussion, then push the latest version of the source code.

Comment: The String is passed normally to respoanseData1 but the client care just read the int and not the string.

Comment: @konstantin, thank you for the update (push)! Please see the update. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Oke its stupid but now I have another issue, since i want to send firstly the nubmer of the connected channels Since without that my game doesnt work. So i firstly want to check if the connected clients are two and then to exchange info. Now it seems that i can send the string but not correctly the number of the connected clietns.

Comment: This is what am trying to do with responseData and responseData1. THe responseData is for sending just the size of the channels and the responseData1 for sending the rest of the info. But now it seems that the client does not received them with specific order.

Comment: For some reason in the second client the varialbe private static volatile int connectedClients = 0;  it is remaining zero.

Comment: Have add also in processingHandler the size of the channels to the responseData responseData1.setIntValue(channels1.size());
            responseData1.setStringValue(requestData.toString());
            ch.writeAndFlush(responseData1);

Comment: @konstantin, yes, exactly as you have just told: `responseData1.setIntValue(channels1.size()); responseData1.setStringValue(requestData.toString()); ch.writeAndFlush(responseData1);`. Do you have any question(s) left?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159696/discussion-between-konstantin-and-sergey-brunov).

Comment: connectedClients  is always zero in the second client.